# Is there a better to write an if statement that evaluates a single flag value change?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, flags

I came upon the following code in a python script:

```
if flag == True:    
       flag = False    
       #Code block XYZ

elif flag == False:    
       #Code block XYZ
```

I think there's just a lot of code repeated (since "Code block XYZ" is exactly the same in both conditional statements). The only objective seems to be to change the value of the flag but since "Code block XYZ" is extremely long, I wonder if there's a better way to avoid repeating all that same code in both if statements.

Comment: How about passing bool value as a function param (inside the XYZ function) and then do required processing?

Comment: Your code does not seem to depend on *flag* at all. What about 'flag = False; code xyz'?

Answer (score 2):

If your XYZ Code is exactly the same in both statements, you can move it out and use the statement to evaluate `flag`, for example:

```
if flag: 
    flag = False
# if you need to do something when it is False then add an else statment here
# XYZ code goes here without if/else
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a ridiculous job of assigning flag=0 every time irrespective of flag's current value, My suggestion is not to use if structure and directly assign  flag=False. For your satisfaction, I suggest the following code:

```
if ((flag==True) | (flag==False)):flag=False
```

Answer (score -2):

if **Code block XYZ** do same thing, then can fix like this.

```
if flag:
    flag = False

if not flag: 
    pass # code
```

---

and the logic change flag to False, anyway and execute. so

```
flag = False
# code here
```

will do same thing

Comment: In this case both the case will executes if flag value is True. If not flag should be either in else part or in elif part.

Comment: given code run Code block anyway if flag is boolean.

Comment: if flag value is True it will executes its part and set flag value to False and then again it will execute if not Flag part as it is value is already false now.

Comment: You do not have to separate else part, cuz `else if not flag` in given code just run same thing

Comment: Just try to print in both the parts and let me know. Hope you will get the point :)

Comment: no way.... if True of False, code execute one time.

`if True` then set flag to False and run code because flag == False
`if False` then run code

Comment: dude at least try and then tell me .. :)

Comment: if flag:
    flag = False
    print '1'
if not flag: 
    print '2'

Comment: Try it... https://gist.github.com/MaybeS/93fa2989a75d3e69203b99f75a7a2098

Comment: You did not understand the purpose of the question maybe i think